# Custom events and parameters not visible in GA4

Tags: google-analytics

We are pushing the events and parameters through below code -

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "Login - Page Load",
  eventModel: {Flavour: "ABC", Country ID: 123, Country Code: "ABC", send_to: "GTM-XXXXX"},
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 123
})
```

However, i don't see events in GA4. I have around 20 custom events configured in the code with parameters. How do i see these events and parameters automatically in GA4? I see them in Google Tag assistant in debug view. Do i need to set tags and triggers for each of the 20 events in Google Tag Manager?

My Expectation was that by setting events in the code and calling GTM id on every website page, events will automatically show up in GA4. Tag manager has only 2 tags created one Events tag for All elements trigger and container tag for GA4 configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First open your devtools and inspect the `collect` Network calls. Make sure you're seeing your event parameters there. They should be in `ep` query parameters. Like SO does here with the percent_scrolled event:

[image]

Then if you do see them, go to GA4 and make sure you've created custom dimensions for all the parameters that you want to report on.

Finally, go to GA4's Explore view and build a report based on your dimensions. May as well go to the data retention settings and set it to 14 months from 2 unless you're not interested in exploring more than 2 months of data history.